# Spring mvc + spring security, a 404 after log in

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm new to spring security and I'm into a small trouble with it.

So I have 2 model classes :

User :

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    @NotEmpty
    private String email;
    @NotEmpty
    private String password;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<UserRole> roles = new HashSet<>();
```

UserRole:

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String role;
    private String description;
```

At the moment of registration user is assigned a `ROLE_USER` by default.

I made own `UserDetailsService`implementation :

```
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(username);
        if (user == null)
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                user.getEmail(),
                user.getPassword(),
                convertAuthorities(user.getRoles())
        );
    }

    private Set<GrantedAuthority> convertAuthorities(Set<UserRole> userRoles) {
        Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
        for (UserRole ur : userRoles) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(ur.getRole()));
        }
        return authorities;
    }
```

And my security config :

```
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/css/**", "/register").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().usernameParameter("email").passwordParameter("password")
                .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/").invalidateHttpSession(true).and().csrf();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }
```

Registration is succesfull in the `/register` controller.

After when I want to login with the same credentials the problem occurs. From the login form I'm sending a POST request to `/login` controller.

Form :

```
<form class="form-signin" action="#" th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please log in</h2>
        <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" th:required="required"></input>
        <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" th:required="required"></input>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

`/login` controller :

```
@PostMapping("/login")
    public String processLogin(){
        logger.debug("processLogin");
        return "secure";
}
```

The `/login` controller should return the `secure` page but instead I'm receiving an 404 error

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Mar 13 21:17:02 CET 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

Like I said, I'm new in spring security and I don't what is wrong ...

Comment: "secure" is a normal HTML page in the same folder as login and register

Comment: please provide details like web.xml and spring config xml files. You are getting 404, means it is not at all reaching to the controller.

Comment: It's a spring boot project so I don't have any config files.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide `authentication-failure-url` in spring security  add this code `formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/loginPage?error")` in security config.

Comment: It didn't help.

Comment: The same, nothing had changed.

Answer (score 0):

I am using an easy way to handle HTTP errors in my Spring MVC + Spring Security app:

I declared all errors I want to handle in web.xml

```
<error-page>
    <!-- Missing login -->
    <error-code>400</error-code>
    <location>/in_general-error</location>
</error-page>
    <error-page>
    <!-- Missing login -->
    <error-code>401</error-code>
    <location>/in_general-error</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <!-- Forbidden directory listing -->
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/in_general-error</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <!-- Missing resource -->
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/in_general-error</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <!-- Uncaught exception -->
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/in_general-error</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <!-- Unsupported servlet method -->
    <error-code>503</error-code>
    <location>/in_general-error</location>
</error-page>
```

As you can see in location there is not a page but an URI. Of course you have to allow access to that URI in your Spring Security configuration. And you have to handle that URI in your Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/in_general-error", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView generalError() {        
        return new ModelAndView("general-error");
    }
```

And thats all. There are other solutions but this is the easiest you can find.

Answer (score 0):

@Bartosz - you need to create your 'secure.html' file in the src/main/resources/templates directory in your project.  Then when your LoginController.java returns "secure" it will find the thymeleaf template file there.

LoginController.java

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    String login(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
        return "secure";
    }
}
```

secure.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body onload="document.f.username.focus();">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <a class="brand" href="https://www.thymeleaf.org"> Thymeleaf - Plain </a>
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a th:href="@{/}" href="home.html"> Home </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <p th:if="${param.logout}" class="alert">You have been logged out</p>
        <p th:if="${param.error}" class="alert alert-error">There was an error,  please try again</p>
        <h2>Login with Username and Password</h2>
        <form name="form" th:action="@{/login}" action="/login" method="POST">
            <fieldset>
                <input type="text" name="username" value="" placeholder="Username" />
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
            </fieldset>
            <input type="submit" id="login" value="login" 
                class="btn btn-primary" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```